# Unable to change NSButton foreground color from XCODE property panel

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I am working on MAC application (Xcode 6.4) and I am trying to change the fore color of NSButton from XCODE property panel but its not getting changed. Am I doing it wrong or is it a bug in XCode?

[image: NSButton]

[image]

[image: Changing Fore Color]

Comment: I'm changing it by clicking on 'Show the Attributes inspector' and then below the "Font" there is text color.. You mean about the text?

Comment: Is it 'Custom Button'? Or normal 'UIButton'?

Comment: no its not a custom button @KananVora its a simple NSButton

Comment: @Patryk Imosa Yes, I am talking about Text Color

Comment: Did you you try what I wrote?

Comment: Yes @PatrykImosa. I selected the button >> went to Attributes inspector >> font >> font panel >> text color and then changed color. Also, there is not Text color option below font as you had said. Just look at the screen shot present in question.

Answer (score 0):

select your button and go to attributes inspector. then select text color, then change it.

select your button ---> go to attributes inspector ---> select text color --->then change the color.

Comment: I have already tried to do it as shown in images if you have seen present in my question. Its not working.

Comment: do you use any plugins for Xcode or which Xcode version do you use

Comment: did you try with a new project. create a new project and only add a button and try to change foreground color and background color. even it does not work, something wrong with your Xcode

Comment: @anuk I also cant change it. Notice that it is for OS X not for IOS, for IOS it works...

Comment: I tried it with new project on 2 different mac. is it working on your mac?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to change it from property panel, but you can change it in your code.

Create a property with this button and in ViewController in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.button.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Title" attributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [NSColor redColor] }];
```

It should work. If there are errors then let me know

Comment: I know I can do it via code but why should I write code when there is an option available in xcode?

Answer (score -1):

You can change the textColor of the 'UIButton' like this:

[image]

Try like this and let me know if any questions...

All the best!!!

Comment: @Karan Vora I am working on MAC app not on IOS app. So there is no UIButton